# Connect Bot Composer to Language Studio questionanswering

Tags: chatbot

I've been using bot composer to connect to QnA maker and the following are required

however I've now been creating a custom questionanswering project in the language studio

so where do i find the equivalent questionanswering values for knowledgebaseID, endpoint key and hostname which i need to connect to this service?

[QnA bot composer required values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nglpr.png)

Comment: have you got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily creating a custom question & answering project in the language studio by installing nuget package- "Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CustomQuestionAnsweringRecognizer" from package manager in the composer.

[image: Custom Question Answering - nuget package]

Just go through its documentation how to use it.